# Deriving formula to solve parabolic equations with variable co-efficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

[image]
[image]

The above is a derivation of a formula to solve parabolic PDE's with variable co-efficients

My question is what exactly are the solutions $X(x)$? Can we find a nice closed form expression for $X(x)$ in the same way we did for $T(t)$?

Comment: Second order linear ODE has no really nice general solution. However, you can find its Wronskian easily.

Comment: No. ODE's with variable coefficients don't generally have "nice" solutions. There are solutions for specific forms of the coefficient functions, though.